# Building visual interface to create code logic for in use in web app

Tags: web, code-generation, lamp, builder

*I am looking for ways to implement visual logic building for non-programmers in my web application (LAMP stack with Phalcon framework).*

**Current situation:**
We have +20 products with different prices. Certain items bought together have special offers.
For example buying item1 and item2 will have their prices halved. But if we add item3 the price will drop only 15%. And so on.

Rules for special offers changes quite often and every time we have to code and change the logic behind it. It's tedious and error prone.

**What I am looking for:**
If we had an interface with all products, prices and certain rule markers - people from sales dept could combine and create their special offers and it would automatically be used in logic behind final price calculations.

At first I imagined some kind of drag and drop interface with all items and mind map like connections with rules between them.

---

As a junior dev I am having a hard time finding a solution to this and I would love some help from others. I could not find a proper source of information regarding visual code logic builders. Any suggestions to APIs or libs would be very welcome.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. You do need to find the right abstraction and data representation of the rules to be build by the rules gui builder if that is what you mean.

Comment: @elpddev Yes, you are right. The GUI should only represent the system in place. As you said I need to find the "right abstraction and data representation". Thanks